# Scorm 2004 save one sco in one time

Tags: sequence, scorm, scorm2004

I create manifest, with multiple sco. I set that when i open sco then is init, set('cmi.success_status','passed'); save(). It's works, but when i open next sco, i see that is ok. Icon on navigation tree is change to 'passed'. But when I refresh page [f5], the first sco i good save, but second sco don't have save data that i set. What's wrong is with my manifest?

```
<organizations default="w2l">
<organization identifier="w2l">
<title>Kurs pisania Beta 1</title>
<item identifier="l0_i" identifierref="l0" isvisible="true">
<title>Wstęp</title>
<item identifier="l1_i" identifierref="l1" isvisible="true"><title>Title1</title></item>
<item identifier="l2_i" identifierref="l2" isvisible="true"><title>Title2</title></item>
<item identifier="l3_i" identifierref="l3" isvisible="true"><title>Title3</title></item>
<item identifier="l4_i" identifierref="l4" isvisible="true"><title>Title4</title></item>


</item>
</organization>
</organizations>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with the run-time implementation within the SCO and not the manifest. Are you calling Terminate in the onunload event? Are you setting cmi.exit to suspend before unloading to ensure that data is persisted?

Comment: i forgot say, that when i don't put in mannifest :<imsss:sequencing><imsss:controlMode choice="true" flow="true"/></imsss:sequencing> all works. But I can't navigate the course. I think problem is: I dont understand Sequencing :) i read, read, read but still have problem with that. And golf examples don't help me :/

Comment: i found problem, it was problem with lms platform and error with sql. They don't save data

Answer (score 0):

I was trying everything.

I try like you said.

On the page i put:

```
            init();
        set('cmi.score.raw','100');
        complete();
        save();
        end(); - send terminate
```

But then i was redirect to page where is write: The current course session has ended. Click to countinue.
Then it's work. But this is the same thing that eariel [f5 after save te complete status].
I wan't save complete, and go to the next page, without visit "the current course session has ended".

If i you link to go to the next page: set('adl.nav.request','continue');end(); student go to the next lesson, but complete status save only on first page.

I put my example here: fratczak.org/files/Scorm.zip
You can click on lesson 'Jak osiągnąć poziom mistrzowski?' and see what happen.